# How do you translate the following phrase?

Tags: palabras-raras

Mientras escuchaba la hermosa canción *texas blues* de Mance Lipscomb, me preguntaron, un amigo, como sería la traducción al español del siguiente fragmento de la canción:

*I ain't got no money, my shoes had done worn thin*

Cuál sería la traducción exacta al español?

Comment: translate.google.com gives almost the exact meaning you're looking for. The problem with the direct translation it gives is that this phrase has "had done worn" and it's difficult for the translator to cope with it but it manages to produce a good output. This answer does not show any research, in Stack Overflow it would be a plz send teh codez question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sólo aclarar que la canción dice:

> [I didn't have no money](https://youtu.be/WZDgWESeZWs?t=57s)

en lugar de `I ain't got no money`, si te das cuenta, la canción habla en todo momento de tiempo pasado.
Por otro lado, yo no intentaría hacer una traducción literal, sino una equivalencia de significados, por ejemplo:

> "No tenía dinero, mis zapatos estaban muy gastados... "

Answer (score 1):

> I ain't got no money

Se traduciría por "no tengo dinero". Curioso que de una doble negación (que no se permite en inglés) pasemos a una sola negación en español (aunque también se podría decir "no tengo ningún dinero").

> my shoes had done worn thin

Podría traducirse como "mis zapatos se han desgastado". ["Desgastar"](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=J7PJ5bqAFDXX2PcGsYnH) es el verbo español para "worn out". "Worn thin" simplemente expresa que la suela se ha ido volviendo cada vez más fina. Una traducción más adecuada, que tenga en cuenta ese "had done" podría ser

> Mis zapatos habían terminado de desgastarse

Comment: ¿Por qué es tan difícil traducir la frase conservando el dialecto? Es decir, ¿por qué, al pasar la frase al español, se corrigen los errores (que, en realidad, no son errores propiamente dichos, sino es la estructura del dialecto del ingles vernacular del sur de los Estados Unidos) gramaticales como la doble negación o el uso peculiar del past perfect?

Comment: @user135395 es difícil porque a veces no hay estructuras equivalentes, y incluso si las hubiese, se tendría que hallarlas en un dialecto particular, y incluso si se las hallase en uno, es muy dudable que las connotaciones del uso de él coincida con el del dialecto del inglés.

Comment: @Diego No es que el inglés no permita la doble negación, sino que el inglés estándar no la permite (y es muy curioso que no la permita).  El inglés antiguo la tenía y está conservada en muchísimos dialectos como el mío.  *done + part.* es un pretérito próximo (un pelín más remote que *acabar de inf.* en castellano) y entonces con *had* en frente, casi me pregunto si se podría traducir al castellano con el poco usado pretérito anterior: «se hubieron desgastado»

Comment: @guifa ***Y** incluso? :)

Comment: @guifa _y_ seguido de _i*_ de debe reemplazar por _e_ (e incluso). _se tendría que hallarlas_ no es la forma correcta, puedes usar _habría que hallarlas_. Por último, repasa el uso de _él_ y _el_ y de _este_ y _éste_, _él_, no va tildado esta vez y está mal utilizado en la frase. ;)

Comment: @guifa. Interesante. La verdad es que no había reparado en lo diferente de los tiempos verbales de ambas frases. Seguramente tu sugerencia es una traducción más acertada que la mía.

Comment: @guifa del uso de "se hubieron desgastado", la forma correcta es _hubieran_, para este caso, y allí pierde sentido su uso. Quizás _se hallaban desgastados_ pueda acomodarse.

Comment: @sergiovelásquez hubieron es la forma correcta del pretérito indefinido, el cual se usa para forma el pretérito anterior (lo que se sitúa cronológicamente antes del pretérito indefinido y después del pluscuamperfecto)

Comment: @guifa El uso de [hubieron](http://www.rae.es/consultas/hubieron), "aparece siempre precedido de nexos como cuando, tan pronto como, una vez que, después (de) que, hasta que, luego que, así que, no bien, apenas" o "como forma de la tercera persona del plural del pretérito perfecto simple o pretérito de indicativo de la perífrasis verbal haber de + infinitivo, que denota obligación o necesidad y equivale a la más usual hoy tener que + infinitivo" (RAE). Y no veo que sea el caso en la frase.

Comment: @SergioVelásquez  El uso que tú citas está explicado en §23.16k de la Gramática y sí obliga adverbios o conjunctivas que indican posterioridad.  Pero fíjate que el párrafo empieza: «**Con las excepciones mencionadas**, el uso antiguo de *hube cantado* ha desaparecido de la lengua actual» (énfasis mío).  El uso en que pensaba yo al sugerir «se hubieron desgastado» era precisamente el que se detalla en §23.16j (es decir, una de las excepciones).  No veo problema con *él* (pronombre) y *el* (artículo), aunque sería posible reemplazar *él* por *este* (pero no *éste* porque *éste* ya no existe)